# VMware Workstation or VirtualBox permanent date setup

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation

How do I fix a date for a virtual machine? Need to use a VS10Beta1 CTP that has time limit and holds some test projects I'd like back.

Comment: What's a "wrokstation"?

Comment: is 'typo' good enough for you, ephilip?

Comment: Just suggesting someone should fix it.  Can't you understand sarcasm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date/time is set within the guest operating system.  If you can boot the VM, disable syncing with the host and change the date/time.

Answer (score 1):

If using VMware Workstation, you can mount the virtual hard drive and copy your files back, or create a new virtual machine and set the VS2010 hard drive as a secondary hard drive, then just copy the files over.